# AzureDevOps Build Rest API: How to get all Warning count in build Task, exceed the limit of 10

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am trying to get on an AzureDevOps project the number of Warning for a build task. But I still only get the first 10 warnings. How do you do it all? I especially need the number of warning, not necessarily the detail of the warning

```
var credential = new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, myPat);
var connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(myCollection), credential);
var buildClient = connection.GetClient<BuildHttpClient>();
var timeline = buildClient.GetBuildTimelineAsync(myProject, myBuildId).Result;
var vsTask= timeline.Records.FirstOrDefault(p => p?.Task?.Name == "VSBuild");
// always 10 utmost  : warning and issues !!
var warning = vsTask.WarningCount;
var issues =  vsTask.Issues;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really strange, but it looks that you cannot go above what is shown here

[image]

There is workaround (but it is a bit ugly). You can load log page and count warnings parsing the page.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var credential = new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, "PAT");
    var connection = new VssConnection(new Uri("https://dev.azure.com/your-organization/"), credential);
    var buildClient = connection.GetClient<BuildHttpClient>();
    var timeline = buildClient.GetBuildTimelineAsync("yoyr project", 377).Result;

    var vsTask = timeline.Records.FirstOrDefault(p => p?.Task?.Name == "VSBuild");
    // always 10 utmost  : warning and issues !!
    var warning = vsTask.WarningCount;
    var issues = vsTask.Issues;
    Console.WriteLine(warning);


    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var response =  client.GetAsync(vsTask.Log.Url);
    var pageContents = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    var realNumberOfWarnings = AllIndexesOf(pageContents, "##[warning]");
    Console.WriteLine(realNumberOfWarnings.Count);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static List<int> AllIndexesOf(string str, string value)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        throw new ArgumentException("the string to find may not be empty", "value");
    List<int> indexes = new List<int>();
    for (int index = 0; ; index += value.Length)
    {
        index = str.IndexOf(value, index);
        if (index == -1)
            return indexes;
        indexes.Add(index);
    }
}
```

I hope it will help.

Please check what Tingluo Huang [MSFT] wrote [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/309080/different-number-of-warnings-reported-from-vsts-bu.html):

> We should only count and store 10 errors/warning (i guess we having
>   some counting bug, so we count to 11), those issues get stored in our
>   backend DB for driving the build summary page render. We don't want to
>   store too many errors/warning since most of the time the first few
>   errors/warnings are key to the problem, and the rest are just noise.

Comment: thank you very much, yes it seems to be a limitation. it's a shame.

To stay in an authenticated context

var logs = buildClient.GetBuildLogLinesAsync(myProject, myBuildId, vsTask.Log.Id).Result;
var warningCount = logs.Count(p => p.Contains("##[warning]"));

Comment: Yes of course. I have public pipelines and thus I could do it as I did.